# jquery: exclude external resources from $(window).load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute some scripts when all the resources on my domain and subdomain are loaded, so I did this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // al my functions here...
}
```

The problem is that there are some external resources (not on my domain and subdomain) that sometimes take longer to load. Is there a way to exclude external resources from the load event?

**EDIT:**
I was hoping to do something like:

```
$(window).not(".idontcare").load(function()
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your external resources rely on a `src` attribute.

If so, in your page source code you could set the `src` attribute of the resources you don't want to wait for, not as `src` but as `external_src`.

Then you could easily do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).load(function(){
        // all your functions here...
    });

    $('[external_src]').each(function() {

        var external_src = $(this).attr("external_src");

        $(this).attr("src", external_src); // now it starts to load
        $(this).removeAttr("external_src"); // keep your DOM clean

        //Or just one line:
        //$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("external_src")).removeAttr("external_src");

    });

});
```

This way the external resources should start loading as soon as just the DOM is ready, without waiting for the full window load.

Comment: Thanks, but this could be acceptable if users are able to load my resources fast, and it's not always true...

Comment: By writing "my resources" you mean "not external"?

Comment: yes, I mean "not external" resources! I'll try your method with the edit and see if it works, even if I would prefer not to have to edit the source html code adding the external_src parameter. but probably it's not possible...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that automatically. But even if it was, you should have anyway add some "idontcare" class on your source HTML code; so, you have just three lines of code to add further.

Answer (score 2):

I have almost same case. But in my case, I want to exclude all iframes that load content from another site (e.g. youtube, vimeo etc). Found a work around, so the scenario is hide 'src' attribute from all iframes when DOM is ready and put it back when window is finish load all another content.

```
(function($){
    //DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var frame = $('iframe'),
            frameSrc = new Array();

        if( frame.length ){
            $.each( frame, function(i, f){
                frameSrc[i] = $(f).attr('src');
                //remove the src attribute so window will ignore these iframes
                $(f).attr('src', '');
            });

            //window finish load
            $(window).on('load',function(){
                $.each( frame, function(a, x){
                    //put the src attribute value back
                    $(x).attr('src', frameSrc[a]);
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You can mark all elements in your site that load external resources by adding a special class,  and change the iframe with `$('.special_class')` or something like that. I dont know if this is the best way but at least it works great in my side :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `window.onload` event is very strict. As you might know it will fire when all und every resource was transfered and loaded, *images*, *iframes*, *everything*. So the quick answer to your question is no, there is no easy-to-use way to tell that event to ignore external resources, it makes no difference there.

You would need to handle that yourself, which could be a tricky thing according to how those resources are included and located. You might even need to manipulate the source code before it gets delivered to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is an async - tag for script tags. You can your includes to:

```
<script src="script_path" async="true"></script>
```

This will not include them to the event.

Comment: This is true only for HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

instead of $(window).load() will help?

The document ready event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet.

Comment: I think OP actually *wants* the behavior from the `window.onload` event, not `DOMContentLoaded`. Just not for external resources as he mentioned.